# Firebase - Bad Request error returned on rebased commit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this exception on my android app but it's something strange because I have returned to a git commit that used to work but now I'm still getting  this error, the same code that worked before now doesn't work(and I havent changed any key or anything like that)

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.auth_success,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(mapIntent);
            }else{
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.auth_fail,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception?